# Adjustment of wort volume when the wort is still hot

Tags: beer, wort, specific-gravity

When calculating the SG of a hot wort so you can decide how much to dilute your wort to achieve the desired dilution and Final gravity is it correct to make the following calculation?

Measure the SG of wort at 70C to be 1040 then:-  1040*(1-0.00025)/(70-20)+1040 assuming my hydrometer is calibrated at 20C = 1060.795?

This seems about right but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to leave this as comments, since it's not quite an answer, but I lack the reputation to leave comments yet.

You might want to consider whether your wort is still 70C when it reaches your measuring device. Every sample might be cooling to room temperature by the time it reaches your hydrometer or refractometer.

After reading a bit about temperature correction for SG, it looks to me like it's a very long polynomial, and won't convert accurately in a linear fashion like you are trying to do. I wanted to include it here but it all the threads I found on it were disputed and vague.

I would also ask- are you sure you need to factor the temperature at all? An SG reading will be affected by temperature, but SG for brewing recipes is just a representation of the ratio of sugars to water. If you know how much fermentables you added, or if you can use a reading to find out how much was extracted, then you will be able to add enough water to meet the desired ratio.

Like I said, it's not really an answer, but I hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to answer my query. I suppose I don't need to know but it would give the advantage of diluting my wort with tap water which isn't sterile but that wouldn't concern me if I was adding it when the wort is still hot enough to kill any bacteria in the tap water. As my practice stands I don't take samples of my wort to measure SG because it risks infection. My practice is to run the wort off into a sterile bucket + lid and get it in my ice bath to cool ASAP. It usually takes 2 hours. By this time the wort is at 20C and ready to take the Final gravity. Obviously I sterilize my hydrometer to do this in the whole batch.if my mash has gone well (I average 86% mash efficiency) and my FG is too high I want to dilute it. I could use kettle water previously boiled and cooled to 20C but I actually use tap water. I gather from professional brewers that this is acceptable practice but as a biochemist I know the wort is at its most funerable stage with respect to getting infected. In practice this has never happened to one of my works but the opportunity is there. Thats why I was thinking convert to SG at a high temperature, calculate what the FG will be and dilute in a more sterile manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to dilute the wort while it's still hot. There's nothing wrong with cooling your wort first and then diluting it. I've done that all my life with partial boils. Cool the hot wort, transfer it to the fermenter, add water. Simple.

If contamination is your concern, simply boil and cool the water used for dilution prior to adding it to the wort. However, I have yet to encounter a problem as a result of cold wort dilution.

Measuring the SG of hot wort with a hydrometer can be done but it's a pain. Also, keep in mind that the volume of hot wort can be up to 4% larger than that of the same wort when cooled due to expansion. That means that your SG will change accordingly during cooling and you must compensate for that in your calculations on top of your hydrometer correction!